# avoiding doplicate lines and getting insert ids after multiple insertion

Tags: php, mysql, sql

First question is I have a sql query like below.. And how to get ids of test, test1 and test2?

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tags (tag_name) VALUES ('test'),('test1'),('test2')
```

There is a table to match tag_id and ann_id(announcements).The structure of the table is

```
tag_id(int 6)
ann_id(int 6)
```

I want to avoid duplicate lines. Is there anything that i can do with mysql for solve this problem? Or I must create a select query and count?

Comment: use UNIQUE to avoid duplicate

Comment: @user3091574 I don't mean using duplicate rows.. I mean duplicate lines..

Comment: what do you mean by lines here ?

Comment: @shatheesh for example ann_id = 7 and tag_id = 3.. There mustn't be the same in another line I mean..

Comment: have a look at `Composite Primary Keys`

Comment: @shatheesh got idea about first question?

Comment: @Yusuf i think possible way is only inserting records one by one. If you are inserting with `PHP` then you could use `mysqli_insert_id()` to get the ids, probably you may know this

Comment: @shatheesh I use PDO..